# two pieces of code, one works, one doesnt, why?

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, qemu

I have two bits of code, which I think work exactly the same:

```
    if (ntohs(tcp_hdr->tcp_dport)==80) {
        char * parser = strtok(string,";;");
        while (parser != NULL){
            char parvar[100];
            strcpy(parvar, parser);
            if(parvar[0] == 'H' && parvar[1] == 'o' && parvar[2] == 's' && parvar[3] == 't') {
                char * substr = extract(parvar, 6, strlen(parvar));
                visited_hosts[hosts_counter] = substr;
                hosts_counter++;
            }
            parser = strtok(NULL, ";;");
        }

        bytes_sent += ((ip_hdr->ip_ttl)-40);
    }
```

and

```
    if (ntohs(tcp_hdr->tcp_sport)==80) {

        char * parser = strtok(string,";;");
        while (parser != NULL){
            char parvar[100];
            strcpy(parvar, parser);
            if(parvar[0] == 'L' && parvar[1] == 'o' && parvar[2] == 'c' && parvar[3] == 'a') {
                char * substr = extract(parvar, 10, strlen(parvar));
                visited_pages[pages_counter] = substr;
                pages_counter++;
            }
            parser = strtok(NULL, ";;");
        }
        bytes_received += ((ip_hdr->ip_ttl)-40);            
    }
```

I have while(1) listener and first piece of code works fine, but second one exits loop after completionof its task with a segmentation fault. I cannot use gdb as I am using QEMU to test my solutions. Do you guys know what might be a problem, or what else can I use to debug c code in QEMU?

Comment: Whe you make "strcpy(parvar, parser);" Does parser has the same value in both options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, you just fell for the fixed limits trap:

You allocate an array of 100 bytes on the stack, then you copy a string of *unknown* size into it (using `strcpy()`). Now, when parser is a string that is longer than 100 bytes, `strcpy()` continues writing past the end of the array, overwriting vital data on your stack, including your functions return address. This is why your program crashes when your function tries to return - it tries to jump to an address that does not exist.

My advise is: Avoid fixed sized buffers at all costs. Avoid *any* fixed limits at all costs. The only exception is when you can *prove* that no future use will ever be able to exceed the limit. Because, whenever you use a fixed limit, I can guarantee you, that someday it will be exceeded and bite you. And finding such a bug to fix it is *much much* more expensive than doing it right the first time.